# PostgreSQL ActiveRecord where returning all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, null

I have this query

```
Person.where('email ~* ?', "(#{params['domains'][0]}|#{params['domains'][1]})")
```

The behavior I want is to return all the people whose email contains one or more of the domains. when my `params = {"domains"=>['gmail.com']}` I get every single record instead of all the people that have gmail.com as part of their domain.

I tested this line

```
Person.where('email ~* ?', "(#{params['domains'][0]}|nil)")
```

and I got only the records with gmail.com

if there isn't a `params['domains'][1]` then it should equal `nil`. What's happening?

from looking at the SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contacts" WHERE (full_name ~* '(jared|friedman)\s?\w?\s?(jared|friedman)') AND (email ~* '(gmail.com|)')
```

it seems the problem is with `(gmail.com|)`. nil isn't being passed in

I could do a sort of hack by conditionally inserting false if domains has a size of one. But there must be a better way

```
params['domains'][1] = false if params['domains'].size < 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"nil"` is not equal to `"#{nil}"`.  The second code evaluates to an empty string.  If you want `nil` as a string, change it to

```
"(#{params['domains'][0]}|#{params['domains'][1] || 'nil'})")
```